# MySQL Select Query to exclude a date

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a table with id, name, dateofentry, dateofexit and information looks like:

```
1, Test1, 2021-03-01, 0000-00-00
2, Test2, 2021-03-02, 2021-03-03
3, Test 3, 2021-03-03, 0000-00-00
4, Test 4, 2021-03-04, 0000-00-00
5, Test 5, 2021-03-04, 0000-00-00
```

Now if do select query and I want to know how many are still active as in have dateofexit is 0000-00-00 the answer should be count of 4 as record with ID 2 left on 2021-03-03.

So the query I have is

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `dateofentry`<='2021-03-04' 
  AND `dateofexit`<='2021-03-04' 
  AND dateofexit='0000-00-00'
```

and it will return following:

```
1, Test1, 2021-03-01, 0000-00-00
3, Test 3, 2021-03-03, 0000-00-00
4, Test 4, 2021-03-04, 0000-00-00
5, Test 5, 2021-03-04, 0000-00-00
```

Which is fine but if I do the select query and change the date to 2021-03-02 as in

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `dateofentry`<='2021-03-02'
  AND `dateofexit`<='2021-03-02'
  AND dateofexit='0000-00-00'
```

it only returns

```
1, Test1, 2021-03-01, 0000-00-00
```

but I want it to return the following:

```
1, Test1, 2021-03-01, 0000-00-00
2, Test2, 2021-03-02, 2021-03-03
```

Please help, in short I want not count or display the one that have exit the system before a given date

Comment: 'AND releasedate=' releasedate?

Comment: releasedate is actually dateofexit and not releasedate

Comment: Please edit your question and not correct it here in the comments.

Comment: AND `dateofexit`<='2021-03-02' - this test makes no sense given that you are only interested in releasedate='0000-00-00' , those with a dateofexit are not in progress (according to your definition)

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `dateofentry`<='2021-03-04' 
  AND `dateofexit`<='2021-03-04' 
  AND dateofexit='0000-00-00'

Comment: As I mentioned releasedate was mistake it should dateofexit

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM `table` 
WHERE `dateofentry`<='2021-03-02'
  OR `dateofexit`<='2021-03-02'
  OR dateofexit='0000-00-00'
```

pleas try this

Comment: This doesnot works it shows all records since everything is OR

Comment: This doesnot works it shows all records since everything is OR

Comment: This doesnot works it shows all records since everything is OR